# How to extract the value at the end of a string in php

Tags: php

In my php code I have an array of variables starting with a word followed by an (random) number:

```
x[0] = 'justaword8'
x[1] = 'justaword5'
x[2] = 'justaword4'
etc.
```

I know i must use a foreach loop, but how to extract the figures at the end of each word? (I assume I could use preg_match() but have no idea how specify that function exactly?)

Comment: Will the random number always be one digit? Or can it be multiple digits, i.e. 12, 122, etc.

Comment: Do you know what word is the prefix?

Comment: is the `justaword` known in advance and constant? then just use a substring operation, e.g. `substr('justaword8', strlen('justaword'))`.

Comment: ^ or just `str_replace`

Comment: @nickb: random number can be 1 or 2 digits

Comment: @Frits van Campen: justaword is known in advance

Comment: Marc B hit it on the head... no need for the overhead of a regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the number varies in length, between one or two digits, you can use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match) like this:

```
foreach( $array as $x) {
    preg_match( '/(\d{1,2})$/', $x, $match);
    echo "The number is: " . $match[1];
}
```

However, since the prefix is known ahead of time, just remove it directly (as per Marc B's comment, with an example usage):

```
$prefix = "justaword";
$length = strlen( $prefix);

foreach( $array as $x) {
    echo "The number is: " . substr( $x, $length);
}
```

Comment: didnt know substr() yet. Thnx (all) for the quick comments and suggestions (!)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this: **[Working eval.in](https://eval.in/45734)** (This will work for one digit)

```
foreach($x as $key => $value)
    echo substr($value,-1);
```

I've updated for the case of two digits, it looks a bit crude without regex however works just fine if for some reason you don't want to use regex: (**[Working eval.in](https://eval.in/45737)**)

```
<?php

$x[0] = 'justaword8';
$x[1] = 'justaword52';
$x[2] = 'justaword4';

foreach($x as $key => $value){
     $y = substr($value,'-2:');
     if(is_numeric($y)) // if last 2 chars are number
         echo $y; // return them
     else
         echo substr($y,1); // return only the last char
}

?>
```

If "justaword" is constant you can just use `str_replace('justaword','',$x[0]);` to remove it.

Comment: Good if just one digit. But OP said it could be two.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary added solution for 1 or 2 digits

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.its only for one digit

```
$str="justaword5";
echo $last_dig=substr($str,strlen($str)-1,strlen($str));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `str_replace` to trim off the prefix.

```
$prefix = "justaword";
$words = array("justaword8", "justaword4", "justaword500");
$numbers = array();
foreach ($words as $word) {
    $numbers[] = str_replace($prefix, "", $word);
}
var_dump($numbers); // gives 8, 4, 500
```

Comment: I think it's `str_replace($prefix, "", $word);`.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
 $vowels = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U");
 $onlyconsonants = str_replace($vowels, "", "Hello World of PHP");
```

output:

```
 `Hll Wrld f PHP`
```

Instead what you should do is let array be the array of all 26 characters.
After all the characters are replaced by a ' ' you can then directly convert a string to number!